# How can I set connection timeout in Retrofit library for Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have used Retrofit library for my Android application.I need to set connection timeout as 120 Sec. How can I do ?

Version:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

OperatingApiClient:

```
    public class OperatingApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://172.16.2.39/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
    }
```

TargetFileApiInterface:

```
public interface TargetFileApiInterface {
@GET("NNGOperating/GetTargetFileList")
Call<TargetFileApiResponse> getTargetFileList(@Query("api_key") 
String apiKey);

}
```

TargetFileApiResponse:

```
    public class TargetFileApiResponse {
    @SerializedName("TargetFileList")
    private List<TargetFile> targetfileslist;

    public TargetFileApiResponse(List<TargetFile> targetfileslist) {
        this.targetfileslist = targetfileslist;
    }

    public List<TargetFile> getTargetfileslist() {
        return targetfileslist;
    }

    public void setTargetfileslist(List<TargetFile> targetfileslist) {
        this.targetfileslist = targetfileslist;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working.

```
public class OperatingApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://172.16.2.39/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set configuration for OkHttp

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(yourTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(yourTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(yourTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

after that, set client for retrofit

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, set httpClient for your retrofit builder.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // I am using 60 seconds you can user your own


 public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())  //setting your custom client
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```